# Insert multiple ActiveRecord objects with single save / commit (Bulk Insertion)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, optimization

I am working in a rails app. I need to insert 5000 item into a table that I'll use later, the problem is when I try doing this:

```
@list.each  do |d|
   dom = Temp.new(:domain => d)
   dom.save
end
```

It takes too much time because for each insertion, there is a commit which takes almost 15X the time of the query itself.

is there a way that I can insert all these objects within the same transaction (with only one commit)?

Comment: Instead of each you can use map, map is more faster than each @list.map{|d| Temp.new(domain: d).save}

Comment: use transaction or extension, check out this [post](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/). I personally use activerecord-import, use `.map` to prepare the data, then import all at same time